# Serverless iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, serverless, http2

I am looking for API to send ios-ios push notifications, without third party servers.
I was trying to reuse Pusher app (https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) but Apple changed networking (e.x. SecureTransport is deprecated) to Network framework which means the lib needs to be rewritten to work again with http2 protocol.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with advanced networking enough to handle SSL, socket, handshakes etc required to achieve this.

Is there any other similar up to date APIs available or a guide to build one?

Comment: Sending a push directly from your app really isn't a good idea; You will need to expose your authentication credentials.  You need some sort of server storage to hold the push tokens anyway.  Depending on the volume you can probably use a free tier of a server-less cloud offering such as Google's Cloud Functions.

Comment: @Paulw11 I forgot to mention, it is for enterprise use only, so exposing credentials probably is not an issue

Comment: You are still going to have to store the push tokens somewhere.  There are some frameworks out there if you search .e.g. https://github.com/alexeyxo/swift-apns but you will find many more for server side.  You can also look at Firebase messaging

Comment: I was able to build something I was asking for from several sources and shared in Github for anyone interested. It’s nowhere close to perfect so modify as you wish. https://github.com/PauliusVindzigelskis/ServerlessPushService